# Typo in API filter documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

> When using unsafe filters, the API returns the highest fidelity data **is** can reasonably access for the given request.

should be

> When using unsafe filters, the API returns the highest fidelity data **it** can reasonably access for the given request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will go out in the next build.